# Extracting characters of a String in PHP after a delimeter

Tags: php, substring

I have a PHP string that contains: Pancake, Waffle -400 (which is some data in my database)
I want to extract 400 from the above string. I have tried using the explode function and strtok.. none seem to work.

This is how I used the explode function:

```
$msg="Pancake, Waffle -400";
$amt=explode("-", $msg);
echo $amt[0];
```

Is there another way to extract the characters after the hyphen?

Comment: Have you done `print_r($amt);` and looked what exactly is inside your array?

Comment: `explode` will return an array. In your case get the 2nd element in `$amt` array.

Comment: One more option is `strstr`

Comment: print_r($amt) did not return anything, which is why I said explode didn't work.

Comment: if `print_r($amt)` return nothing, above code is not your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use substr and strpos:

```
$msg="Pancake, Waffle -400";
echo substr($msg, 0, strpos($msg, '-'));
```

if you only want the '400' part:

```
$msg="Pancake, Waffle -400";
echo substr($msg, strpos($msg, '-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some regex solution?

```
$msg = "Pancake, Waffle -400";
$regex = '~-?\d+~';
preg_match($regex, $msg, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Now, `$match[0]` holds `-400`. See a <kbd>[demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/G3nvR6)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the eventual problem of hyphens in the data before the last one, I would use [strrchr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php), like this:

```
$msg = "Pancake, Waffle -400";
$amt = substr(strrchr($msg, "-"), 1); // substr removes the '-' from the result
echo $amt;
```